# Java App developed in Eclipse don't work in web page

Tags: java, html, eclipse, japplet

I have developed a small JApplet for a site. 
It's the first time I do such a thing, so it's probably a stupid error or misundestanding, but I can't find out what it is.

Here is the first class called from the HTML:

```
public class MapGenerator extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int numero_immagini;
    private BufferedImage[] images;
    private int[] floors;

    private static final String N_IMMAGINI = "numero_immagini";
    private static final String IMMAGINE = "immagine";
    private static final String PIANO_IMMAGINE ="numero_piano";


    public void init() {

        numero_immagini = Integer.parseInt(this.getParameter(N_IMMAGINI));

        images = new BufferedImage[numero_immagini];
        floors = new int[numero_immagini];

            for(int i=0; i< numero_immagini; i++) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(this.getParameter(IMMAGINE+i));
                    images[i] = ImageIO.read(url);
                    floors[i] = Integer.parseInt(this.getParameter(PIANO_IMMAGINE+i));
                } catch (IOException ioe) {}
            }    
    }

    public void start() {

        Editor ed = new Editor(this.getContentPane(), images, floors);

        this.setSize(400, 400);

        this.add(ed.getPanel());

        Toolkit kit = this.getToolkit();
        Dimension dim = kit.getScreenSize();
        this.setBounds(dim.width/4, dim.height/4, dim.width/4, dim.height/4);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<applet code="MapGenerator.class"
    archive="MapGenerator.jar"
    width= 400 height = 200>

        <param name=numero_immagini value=1>
        <param name=immagine0 value="IMG_20111009_171138.jpg">
        <param name=numero_piano0 value=0>
</applet>
```

In Eclipse I haven't any problem at all, but when I tried with Chrome the page show only a gray box.

Thank to all for help.

EDIT

The app cannot load images from the link that I pass.

It trows, testing with a random link image

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.hyros.net:80 connect,resolve)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Have you checked the security options of Chrome?

Comment: It doesen't work also with FireFox...

Comment: Have you checked the security options of FireFox? What about the java console, do you see any output there? By the way, the HTML is missing some tags, or do you just omit them in the post?

Comment: Finally I successed to open the java console.
It's a nullPointerExcpetion, the app isn't loading the image from the link.

Comment: AppletViewer is always nice, as it has the console active by default.  It is in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code, and not the way I use HTML, the jar file or other things, so I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624572/java-applet-cant-load-images-from-web), to describe the problem in a more correct way.

Thank you for your answers.